# Where does jquery put .val() on a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery (all versions tested up through 2.1.0) allows me to call `.val("some value")` on a `DIV` object to set a value on the `DIV`. It is not displayed and doesn't show up as an HTML5 data property in Chrome Developer Tools. And yet I can fetch the result later with a call to `.val()`.

For example (from http://jsfiddle.net/X2nr6/ ):

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display: none;">Some text</div>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#mydiv').val('A value attached .');
$('#debug').text( $('#mydiv').val() );
```

Displayed result:

```
A value attached.
```

Where is the value stored? Not knowing where it is stored makes me worry that I am relying on a hack.

Comment: `console.log($('#mydiv'));` - you'll see it in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is just assigning to a `value` property on the `div` object (the [`HTMLDivElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#htmldivelement) instance for that `div`), even though it doesn't normally have one. Creating new properties on elements is allowed in every browser I've ever seen, so it works. I wouldn't use `val` with `divs` on a regular basis, though.

[Here's](http://jsbin.com/bavup/1) a non-jQuery example:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
console.log('value' in div); // false, divs don't normally have a value property
div.value = 42;
console.log('value' in div); // true, we've created a property on the element
console.log(div.value);      // 42
```

Or [the same sort of thing](http://jsbin.com/bavup/2) using jQuery:

```
var $div = $("<div>");
display(typeof $div.prop('value'));
$div.val(42);
display(typeof $div.prop('value'));
display($div.prop('value'));
```

This business of creating new, custom, non-standard properties on elements is called creating "expando" properties. They *can* be very handy. (jQuery uses them internally, for instance, to manage the `data` cache and a few other things — if you look closely at a DOM element you've *set* data on using `data`, you'll see a property with a name like `jQuery1110028597884019836783`; that's the key jQuery uses to find the element's data in jQuery's internal data cache. jQuery doesn't store the *data* in an expando on the element, because of IE garbage collection issues; it stores the key there, and the data in a JavaScript object.)

Comment: +1 For giving it a name "expando properties" for further Googling.

Answer (score 2):

It stores it on a `value` property on the DOM object. You can see if by running your code and then inspecting the element in a DOM inspector. In Chrome, the `value` property will be listed under `div#mydiv` in the properties tab.

[image: screenshot showing where the properties tab in Chrome is]

HTMLDivElement objects don't officially support such a property, so you are relying on a hack.

Use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to store arbitrary data on an element.

```
$('#mydiv').data("myCustomValue", 'A value attached .');
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the above answers are accurate, I'd like to complete something out.

jQuery is designed around the concept of wrapping all HTML elements in the jQuery object.  That jQuery object happens to be an array that can hold more than one element.

jQuery also goes out of its way to hide this fact from you so that the average jQuery developer never has to worry about exactly what he has -- simply call the right method and the magic happens.

(You see this if you do a `$(".someClassYouHaveLotsOf").hide()` or $(".someClassYouHaveNoneOf").hide()`.)

jQuery's `val()` method is just a wrapper for accessing an HTML `input` element's `value` property.  Since jQuery doesn't throw errors unless there is really no way what-so-ever, it silently *helps* you by accessing the `value` property on whatever HTML element it happens to have.  `div` `span` or whatever.

In most browsers, this works -- mostly enough.

If you are really interested in setting values on HTML elements for use later, the `data()` method is far better suited.  Straight HTML would use `<element>.setAttribute("data-key", "value");`

*And that is about the only time you'll see me using the HTML attributes over properties, BTW.*